# Question about Wacom tablet performance with LR?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Would it be on-topic to ask a question about using a Wacom tablet with LR CC?  Certain operations (straighten, spot, brush) that work just fine with the mouse seem to hang or slow down inordinately when being performed with the tablet.  My question would ask if there's a configuration option that needs to be changed to make things work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems on topic to me -- you're asking about post-processing equipment/tools. From the Help Center, [What topics can I ask about here?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> If you have a question about …
>
> - photographic processing or retouching
> - using photographic equipment
>
> … then you're in the right place to ask your question!

I would assume there might be more people who use Wacom tablets in the graphicdesign.stackexchange.com site. However, I'm fairly sure more Lightroom users are here at Photo.SE. So which site captures more of the intersection of Wacom + Lightroom users, is probably a toss-up.